# lazy load with large number of images

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I have this code for lazy load images:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.imgli').each(function(){
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src")).removeAttr('data-src');
        }
    });
});
```

It works with about 700 images, but I'm interesting - what about 20.000 images (max)?

Is there any way to check this, without really loading 20.000 images, because I don't have so much of them, for now.

Each image is about 100kb max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** you can always copy your existing images to make it 20.000 though it is a little bit pointless.

**Secondly** you can force reload the picture every time it appears in a viewport.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.imgli').each(function(){
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src") + "?" + $.now());
        }
    });
});
```

So you can just scroll the page and see how the pictures are getting loaded every time they appear in a viewport.

**Additionally** eavoid using `$(this)` more than it's necessary.

A better way is to save it to a variable. That way you save memory.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.imgli').each(function() {
        var image = $(this);
        if (image.isInViewport()) {
            image.attr("src", image.attr("data-src") + "?" + $.now());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in that case maybe better - `var image = $('.imgli')` - and place it before ` $('.imgli').each(function() {...`

Comment: @puerto No actually. Because then you don't point to a current image element but to all.

Comment: I see, but in your code jquery also takes `imgli` each time as an object and converts them into a variable, isn't it?

Comment: @puerto Yes, but it takes the current element and it does it for every element that appears in a viewport. And in your suggested solution you would apply the code for every image and not just the current one. It does not convert it into a variable, but it just saves it into a variable.